# Create row in html table which does not have id and class

Tags: javascript, html-table, forms

I would like to create one additional  row in HTML Table which is very common and can be done if we have id or class available of that table.
But in my case I have one page which contains many forms and tables.
But in all those I have one form which contains only one element i.e table and I would like to create one more row and move few columns from 1st row to newly created row.
For this I have created simple HTML page.Please find below code and help me to achieve my output.

```
<h:form id="myForm">
        <table>
          <tr>
                <td id="col1">Item Info</td>
                <td id="col2">Description</td>
                <td id="col3">Product</td>
                <td id="col4">Keywords</td>      
                <td id="col5">Documents</td>
                <td id="col6">Image</td>
                <td id="col7">Video</td>                
           </tr>
        </table>    
</h:form>
```

Here Ia m getting output like 
**Item Info Description Product Keywords    Documents   Image   Video**

But I want to achieve something like below:

**Item Info Description Product Keywords

NEW CELL1 Documents Image   Video**

means I would like to remove few columns from existing row and I would like to add it in newly created row.
For this I have written Javascript like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function() {
          split();
    };
    function split() {          

        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");       
        var table = form.elements[0];
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        tr.id="row2";
        table.appendChild(tr);
        var cell = tr.insertCell(0);
        cell.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
        var col5 = document.getElementById("col5");
        tr.appendChild(col5);
        var col6 = document.getElementById("col6");
        tr.appendChild(col6);
        var col7 = document.getElementById("col7");
        tr.appendChild(col7);           
    }   

    </script>
```

Here, My problem is this entire form will be generated automatically so I can't give the Id for the table and with this script it is not identifying my table when I am giving form.elemets[0];

I want to find table element so that I can create row in that table.

Comment: You mean you just want to give your table an `id`? as in `form.id = 'newForm'`?

Comment: Is [jquery](https://jquery.com/) an option?

Comment: If I can give Id then I will be able to get my table through that id.
Or Is there any direct way to get that table without id?

I just want to get my table element so I can add new row in that whether directly or by giving id also I am ok.

@stwilz  any idea how to give id to that table?

Comment: @JonP I don't have any experience in jquery
But if you have any idea then I will try that as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the table by doing this:

- Get one of the elements in a table row, and get the parent node until you've got the table. In this case you could do `document.getElementById('col1').parentNode.parentNode`

And just to ease things,

- You can insert this string `'</tr><tr>'` in a row, after a table cell, to easily create a new row.

This should be better than `document.getElementsByTagName('table')`, because if you have lots of tables which are far away, it will take more time to find your table's index in that array.

Comment: Thanks buudy....!!!!
It Works for me. 

document.getElementById('col1').parentNode.parentNode is returning my table element.

Thank you once again :)

Comment: Well, thanks to you, I have 71 rep now. You can use this for all elements to find their parents, or "grandparents".

Answer (score 1):

Use `getElementsByTagName` to get the table from within your form, which has an ID

```js
window.onload = function() {
  split();
};

function split() {

  var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
  var table = form.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];


  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  tr.id = "row2";
  table.appendChild(tr);
  var cell = tr.insertCell(0);
  cell.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
  
  /*Your original code produces duplicate IDs which is a BAD thing*/
  var col5 = document.getElementById("col5");
  /*Update new Id*/
  col5.id += "_new";
  tr.appendChild(col5);
  var col6 = document.getElementById("col6");
  /*Update new Id*/
  col6.id += "_new";
  tr.appendChild(col6);
  var col7 = document.getElementById("col7");
  /*Update new Id*/
  col7.id += "_new";
  tr.appendChild(col7);
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="col1">Item Info</td>
      <td id="col2">Description</td>
      <td id="col3">Product</td>
      <td id="col4">Keywords</td>
      <td id="col5">Documents</td>
      <td id="col6">Image</td>
      <td id="col7">Video</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

You also have a mismatch of column numbers, with the code provided you originally have 7 columns and only insert 4, this will produce inconsistent results, make sure to use the `colspan` attribute as needed.

Comment: Thanks @JonP

Actually I tried before like 
var table = form.getElementsByTagName("table");
but it was not returning my table element now I understood that I have to give index as well like
var table = form.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

So it will return table element.

If I have multiple tables then I can use [0],[1] and [2] right?

Comment: Correct, if you have multiple tables in that `form` node. Unless is a method that specifcally returns one element (getElementById, querySelector), the method will return an array of found nodes so you need an index etc. It may be an array of 1, but it is still an array.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use JavaScript's `querySelector` method to select the table data you want to remove from the document.

Something like `var rowToDeleteOrAddTo = document.querySelector("#myForm > table > tr > td");` should help you get there. You'll need to lookup [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to get the specific selectors you need. You may need to use the `textContent` property once you have a node to make sure you are deleting the right one.